# Building an Android app PhoneGap keyboard '7' closes app

Tags: android, cordova

I'm building an app with PhoneGap and when I input the number '7' into a text field, the app closes. This only happens on my Nexus 10, but not my Galaxy Skyrocket. What could be the cause?

Comment: Can you share what kind of input you ask from the user? A little code won't hurt.

Comment: @wmfairuz I took out all other code and it's just <input type="text">

Comment: Did you tried to looks into solutions in the link I gave?

Comment: @wmfairuz Yes, that solution worked!